# I need the user input to go on a new row using vba

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a code where the user inputs some information, and it compares it to a table, and if it finds a match, it puts the user information in the new row created. 
I am having trouble adding the information to the created row. Here is my code

```
Sub findData()
    Dim workflow As String
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    workflow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c5").Value
    servergri = Sheets("sheet1").Range("c9").Value
    gridf = Sheets("sheet1").Range("c9").Value
    finalrow = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("c100").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 3) = workflow Then
            If Cells(i, 4) = servergri Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 8)).Select
                If ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Then
                    'what do I put so that workflow , sergri, gridf, information will go to the new row create?
                ElseIf Cells(i, 5) = gridf Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 8)).Select
                    If ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Then
                    Else

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What information do you want to put in the new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start here.  Apparently, you are looping through rows on Sheets("Sheet3") looking to insert a row if the criteria matches your user's input.

I combined all your if statements into one, fully qualified the references to cells on Sheet3 and added some sample code to demonstrate how to add data to the new row.

```
Sub findData()
    Dim workflow As String
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        workflow = .Range("C5").Value
        servergri = .Range("C9").Value
        gridf = .Range("C9").Value
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        finalrow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 5 To finalrow
            If .Cells(i, 3) = workflow And (.Cells(i, 4) = servergri Or .Cells(i, 5) = gridf) Then

                .Rows(i).Insert
                'Add new information to the new row.  
                'The new row number is still = i

                .Cells(i, 1) = "???"
                .Cells(i, 2) = "???"
                .Cells(i, 3) = "???"
                .Cells(i, 4) = "???"

                'If you only want to add one row then your should exit the loop
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Does this help?  Do you need a clarification?

Answer (score 0):

See my code below for a comparison to yours.  This should do what you want, but it is untested:

```
Sub findData()
Dim workflow As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

workflow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c5").Value
servergri = Sheets("sheet1").Range("c9").Value
gridf = Sheets("sheet1").Range("c9").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("c100").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 3) = workflow Then
        If Cells(i, 4) = servergri Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 8)).Copy
            Range(Cells((i+1),3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ElseIf Cells(i, 5) = gridf Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 8)).Copy
            Range(Cells((i+1),3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Jason, but I don't want add in the column, not the one we are comparing it too. I want to add the one that the user input on Sheet1 @jason

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly in that the user is entering data on sheet3 and the table is on sheet1? If not, please clarify what is going on here, so that I can help you fix this code.

Comment: The user is entering the data on sheet 1 and then from there it goes to sheet 3 to look for something similar. If it finds one then it add a row and it add the information that the user put on sheet 1